# Mocked patch of os.listdir not working for unittesting

Tags: python, unit-testing, mocking, patch

I have a class method that I am trying to test that requires two patched methods, `ConfigB.__init__` and `listdir`:

```
from os import listdir
from config.ConfigB import ConfigB

class FileRunner(object):
  def runProcess(self, cfgA)
    cfgB = ConfigB(cfgA)
    print(listdir())
```

I have the following test set up:

```
import unittest
import unittest.mock imort MagicMock
import mock
from FileRunner import FileRunner

class TestFileRunner(unittest.TestCase):
  @mock.patch('ConfigB.ConfigB.__init__')
  @mock.patch('os.listdir')
  def test_methodscalled(self, osListDir, cfgB):
    
    cfgA = MagicMock()
    fileRunner = FileRunner()

    cfgB.return_value = None
    osListDir.return_value = None

    fileRunner.runProcess(cfgA)
```

Now the patched mock and return value works for `ConfigB.ConfigB`, but it does not work for `os.listdir`. When the `print(listdir())` method runs I get a list of file in the current directory, not a value of `None` as I specified in the patched return value. Any idea what is going wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to patch your relative path to your code. `patch('os.listdir')` doesn't works because you need to patch this:

```
@mock.patch("path.to.your.pythonfile.listdir")
```

Try with that.

Comment: Yes that worked! I updated @mock.patch('os.listdir') to @mock.patch('FileRunner.listdir') and it is returning the expected value.